# How to use local plugins with cloud builds in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I created a CocoaPods plugin for my NativeScript app using the following instructions:
https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods

I am able to run the app in local mode, but when I try cloud builds, I get the following error:

> Could not install from "../my-plguin" as it does not contain a package.json file.

I believe it is not uploading the plugin for cloud builds.

What is the workaround for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You do have `package.json` in your local plugin but still cloud build gives that error, am I right?

Comment: That's correct. package.json exists and local build works flawlessly.

Comment: Did you try `file:my-plguin`, assuming `my-plugin` folder is at root level of the project.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for updating, I posted same as answer so it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below syntax in dependencies of `package.json`

```
....
"my-plguin": "file:my-plguin",
....
```